# Find words with this prefix

Tags: c++, performance, strings

This function (`find_prefix`) is supposed to find words starting with a given prefix in a container. The container is sorted. This function is a fairly performance-critical part of the code, so I am open for any optimization suggestions. Here is a brief usage case; `test_in` is [a file](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words) with `\n` separated English words:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <tuple>
#include <fstream>

template <typename It_beg, typename It_end, typename Prefix>
auto find_prefix(const It_beg beg,
                 const It_end end,
                 Prefix prefix)
{
  auto low = std::lower_bound(beg, end, prefix);
  ++prefix.back();
  auto up = std::lower_bound(beg, end, prefix);
  return std::make_tuple(low, up);
}

int main()
{
  std::string s;
  std::fstream file("test_in");
  if (!file)
  {
    std::cerr << "Failed to open the file\n";
    return -1;
  }

  std::vector<std::string> svec;
  svec.reserve(470000);

  while (file >> s)
  {
    svec.push_back(s);
  }

  std::sort(svec.begin(), svec.end());

  while (std::cin >> s)
  {
    auto [beg, end] = find_prefix(svec.cbegin(), svec.cend(), s);
    std::copy(beg, end, std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
  }

  return 0;
}
```

When the input is "stack" we get this output:

```
stack
stack's
stack-garth
stackable
stackage
stacked
stackencloud
stacker
stackering
stackers
stacket
stackfreed
stackful
stackgarth
stackhousiaceous
stacking
stackless
stackman
stackmen
stacks
stackstand
stackup
stackups
stackyard
```

Comment: I don't think this works. If `prefix.back()` is already the max value the result will be incorrect (and incrementing the max value will also be undefined behaviour for signed types).

Comment: `beg` and `end` of different types?

Comment: I recommend creating an example (a small file with includes, the code above, and some usage cases). Some more elaboration on the code, the problem and conditions in which the code will be run (input patterns, whether from file or not, etc) will be welcome too. I know the code is short, but there can be a lot to say about it.

Comment: @Incomputable is it alright now?

Comment: @vnp tried to be as general as possible honestly

Comment: @user673679 do you suggest I check for the overflow case in the function?

Comment: @Ayxan, certainly. Lets see what others think

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. As you are effectively reading the whole file `test_in` into memory in lots of small independent chunks, consider a different approach:

   1. Read the whole file as one big chunk, or preferably simply map it.
   2. Put `std::string_view`s into that array in the vector, instead of strings.

   Most `std::string`s employ SSO, meaning there are two possible states (external string, active SSO), in contrast to the single one for `std::string_view`. Thus, no branch-misprediction.

   Additionally, `std::string` is generally at least twice the size of `std::string_view`, so this about halves the size of the vector's data.
   Due to allocator overhead, all the small bits of string data would also together likely need considerably more space than that one big chunk.
2. You copy the prefix on calling `find_prefix()`. Better pass a view.
3. When you know where the range you want starts, you know it won't end earlier.
4. `++prefix.back();` is blatantly wrong.

   1. If the prefix is empty, it's Undefined Behavior.
   2. If it causes signed overflow, it's Undefined Behavior.
   3. If it causes unsigned wrap-around, you simply get a completely wrong end-position, which might even lie before the start-position.

   I suggest simply writing your own comparator and using `std::upper_bound()` too, as it is intended to be used.

   Be aware that `char` is treated as `unsigned char` for comparison by `std::char_traits<char>`. You probably want to mirror that, especially as you used that rule when sorting... I won't go to the trouble of staying that general.
5. `std::equal_range()` with a custom comparator does what you want:

   ```
   template <class RandomAccessIterator>
   auto find_prefix(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last, std::string_view prefix) {
       return std::equal_range(first, last, prefix,
           [n = prefix.size()](std::string_view a, std::string_view b) noexcept {
               return a.substr(0, n) < b.substr(0, n);
       });
   }
   ```
6. You don't need `std::make_tuple` in C++17. Just use `std::tuple` directly:

   ```
   return std::tuple{low, up};
   ```
7. By the way, `return 0;` is implicit for `main()`.